# Call function inside module on javascript?

Tags: javascript, module, three.js

I'm starting a project that uses three.js library, and I will use also a parallax library. The 3D effects will be only decorative, but parallax will trigger it.

I modified this example and works fine for me:
demo: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text_shapes
code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_text_shapes.html

...but I need to send the title of every section (when the user enter on it by scrolling down) to the 3D script code, and it is closed inside a module.

...How to to it? I'm newbie into three.js and modules, and want to keep the parallax as is (outside module, because it's a well-known library and part of developed yet project)

Maybe the right way is transform the sample code, without modules... but I'm lost with it... for example, the starting part of JS in module, are:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { SVGLoader } from './jsm/loaders/SVGLoader.js';
import { FontLoader } from './jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
```

...how to do it without modules / import?

Thanks in advance

==================================

I add an example (maximum simplified) about what I need (and not works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - simple text from json</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            init();
            function init() {
                function hi( text) {
                    alert(text);
                }
            } // end init
        </script>
        <script>
            init().hi("hi world");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. Modules are bundled in a single js file, so they are not really separated. You can export a variable like :
`export const title = "Your title"` and then use it wherever you want, it will keep a reference to the original variable, so if you are going to change the value later on, it will keep being updated in all your modules.

Comment: Hi Cesare. Thank you for your reply. But I just need to do the opposite: call a function (custom function) inside the isolated module example from outside, and pass the new title to it...

Comment: Modules are not isolated. Just use those variables as you would normally do with another default declared variable.

Comment: Thank you again, Cesare. I added an example in the starting message, maybe now you can see what I need and can help me...

Comment: Why would you be trying to write inline scripts if you have different modules ? Don't do that... Inline scripting modules import is not natively supported.  Just place your js code in *.js files, and reference them into `<script type="module" src="file.js"/>` or even better use a module bundler. ( `init().hi()` is not javascript, init() returns undefined and you can't access closures as if they were properties )

Comment: This is just a sample, simplified sample, that what I need... maybe isn't possible, I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this turning the code into regular JS, not module JS.

In the library three.js, there is for each control a version for module (into /jsm folder) and normal JS version (/js folder).

Also changed the main file three.module.js for three.js file.

Thank you